# AdsmClientService Event ID 4099

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-event-log

I'm getting a bunch of this erorr message in our server:

> ANS4987E Error processing
>   '\FE01\c$\Windows\System32\config\RegBack\SECURITY': the
>   object is in use by another process

The server has about 20GB of RAM and 8 CPUs running on Windows Server 2008 R2. I've been researching and it looks like this is somewhat related to the storage? I'm not sure what to do or how to resolve this.

Can I please get some insight about this error and any known resolutions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try following up with this article from IBM: "ANS4987E ANS1802E with system files": http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21407564